# How to create a pointer to a 2d character array and then print the output

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char map [3][6] = {
            {'a','.','.','.','.','.'},
            {'.','.','.','.','.','.'},
            {'.','.','.','.','.','.'}
    };//Create a new game map
    char* newmap = map;
    printf("%c",newmap); //Print first element
    return 0;
}
```

The code I have does not work. I am trying to make a pointer to map[3][6] and then be able to print the array from the pointer.

Comment: Don't forget about the `'\0'` required to treat an array as a character **string**. Your pointer must be `char (*newmap)[6] = map;` to use as you have shown on a character basis. Use `putchar (*newmap);` to output a single character.

Comment: @Lucas - yep, right you are. I edited the comment -- good catch. (but I will let you in on secret... `char **ptr = & newmap;` is very very wrong. Where will `ptr` point after you do `ptr++`? -- hint: it will depend on `sizeof (a_pointer)` on the architecture you are using -- not what you want)

Comment: No worries -- this is just one of the normal hurdles in learning that everybody has to come to terms with about arrays and pointers.

Answer (score 2):

You have a misconception about pointers and arrays. When you declare:

```
char map [3][6];
```

You have declared an array of `char[6]` arrays (e.g. an array of arrays). To understand what is happening, you have to understand *Array/Pointer Conversion* governed by [C11 Standard - 6.3.2.1 Other Operands - Lvalues, arrays, and function designators(p3)](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p3)

> (p3) Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` operator, the
> `_Alignof` operator, or the unary `'&'` operator, or is a *string
> literal* used to initialize an array, an expression that has type
> *"array of type"* is converted to an expression with type *"pointer to type"* that points to the initial element of the array object and is
> not an lvalue.

(**note:** C17 removes `_Alignof` as an exception)

Applying array pointer conversion, on access `map` is converted to a pointer of type `char (*)[6]` (a *pointer-to-array-of* `char[6]`). So to use `map` and `newmap` as shown, you would need:

```
char (*newmap)[6] = map;
```

Then, to output a single character, you would use `putchar (**newmap);` which would output the first character in the first 6-character array. Pointer arithmetic advances by `sizeof (*newmap)` (which is an array of `char[6]`). So `putchar (*newmap[1]);` would output the first character of the 2nd row in the 2D array.

Comment: `putchar( newmap[1])` gives you an error, since `newmap[1]` is of type `char*`.  `puts( newmap[1])` will give second row.  I checked in my system. Please check.

Comment: @KrishnaKanthYenumula Yikes, good catch. `newmap[1]` is type `char[6]`, so you are correct we need `*newmap[1]` -- thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Multi-Dimensional Array is also stored as a collection of it's Fewer Dimensional Arrays.
Two-Dimensional Array is stored as an Array of Single Dimension Arrays.

In the Above Problem, you have two Dimensional Array of map [3][6] which is stored as an Array which stores 3 single-dimensional arrays each of size 6. Thus map [3][6] will return a pointer to a single-dimensional array having 6 elements in its every index.

So a pointer should be like char (*ptr)[6] = map ;

Now we would have a pointer through which we can access the array.

ptr[0] will be ['a','.','.','.','.','.'] and ptr[0][0] will be 'a'

For a clearer explanation, you can watch the pointer series of MyCodeSchool on YouTube.

[youtube link to pointer video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_j5lhHWkbnQ&list=PL2_aWCzGMAwLZp6LMUKI3cc7pgGsasm2_&index=11)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char map [3][6] = {
            {'a','.','.','.','.','\0'},
            {'.','.','.','.','.','\0'},
            {'.','.','.','.','.','\0'}
    };//Create a new game map
    char (*newmap)[6] = map;
   
   for( int i=0;i<3;i++)
   {
     printf("%s\n",newmap[i]); 
   }
    return 0;
}
```

`\0` must be appended to get desired output. As David pointed out `char (*newmap)[6]` is a pointer to an array of six elements ( `char[6]`).
The output is:

```
a....
.....
.....
```